# how to clear a auto-complete field in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I used  md-autocomplte to enter a contact name.But when I close the view and reopen it is still showing the previuos contact name at "To" field. how to clear this one. 
Here is my code.

```
<md-autocomplete flex="" required="" ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
                                 md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
                                 md-input-name="autocompleteField" 
                                 md-input-minlength="2" 
                                 md-input-maxlength="18"                                 
                                 md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" 
                                 md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
                                 md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" 
                                 md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
                                 md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" 
                                 md-item-text="item.display" 
                                 md-floating-label="To:">
                <md-item-template>
                    <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
                </md-item-template>

                </md-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a special function to clear up the model value value for you:

```
//in controller
 vm.clear = function() {
    vm.selectedItem = null;
    vm.searchText = '';
  }

//in html
    <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="vm.clear()">Reset</md-button>
```

Check this demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waEzgv

Comment: can we call clear function with out reset button?can I keep this function in md-auto complete directive?

Comment: the button there is just an example. the main thing is a function it calls - which puts : vm.selectedItem = null; vm.searchText = ''; - that's what you need to do in your code when leaving the view or opening it again